# AS3: can't addchild indexed movieclips into a sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, addchild

I'm creating a dynamic blocked terrain in flash (AS3), and everything goes fine with it, the terrain is correctly placed. But I need to include collisions and I want the blocks to be within a movieclip (sprite), so I can test the collision with the terrain itself.

Ps: I don't know if it would be good to test the collisions with each block individually because I'll use a enterframe function and the block generation is dynamic.

The problem I'm facing is that I have a sprite called blockHolder, but I can't addChild the blocks to it.

Here's the code (I simplified it so we have the blocks being created in cascade if you addChild them into the stage directly, like *addChild(clonedSquare)*.

The error I'm receiving:
*TypeError: Error #1009: Can't access property or method of a null object reference.*

```
var blockHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();

var clonedSquare = new square();

var lowestPoint:int = 10;
var highestPoint:int = 20;
var areaLenght:int = 10;

function createLvl():void
{
    for (var i:Number = 0; i<(areaLenght); i++)
    {
        clonedSquare = new square();
        clonedSquare.x = i * clonedSquare.width;
        //sets the height of the first block
        if (i == 0)
        {
            var firstY:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*((lowestPoint-highestPoint))+highestPoint)*clonedSquare.height;
            clonedSquare.y = firstY;
            trace("terrain begins " + firstY + " px down");
        }
        else
        {
                var previousId:Number = i - 1;
                clonedSquare.y = getChildByName("newSquare"+previousId).y + clonedSquare.height;
        }
        //sets the entity (block) name based on the iteration
        clonedSquare.name = "newSquare" + i;
        //adds the cloned square
        blockHolder.addChild(clonedSquare);
    }
    addChild(blockHolder);
}

createLvl();
```

Comment: are you asking why you are getting that error?

Comment: Before `blockHolder.addChild(clonedSquare)`, what do you get if you `trace(blockHolder)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed the error. I am still not clear as to what you're asking for. Basically I add each block to an array and reference the block that way. Your `clonedSquare.y = getChildByName("newSquare"+previousId).y + clonedSquare.height;` was throwing the error. Also your firstY was placing the first block way off my stage so I just set it to 0 as firstY

```
var blockHolder:Sprite  = new Sprite();
var squares:Array       = [];
var lowestPoint:int     = 10;
var highestPoint:int    = 20;
var areaLenght:int      = 10;

function createLvl():void
{
    for (var i:Number = 0; i<(areaLenght); i++)
    {
        var clonedSquare = new square();
        clonedSquare.x = i * clonedSquare.width;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            var firstY:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*((lowestPoint-highestPoint))+highestPoint)*clonedSquare.height;
            //clonedSquare.y = firstY;
            clonedSquare.y = 0;
            trace("terrain begins " + firstY + " px down");
        }
        else
        {
            clonedSquare.y = squares[i - 1].y + clonedSquare.height;
        }
        blockHolder.addChild(clonedSquare);
        squares.push(clonedSquare);
    }
    addChild(blockHolder);
}
createLvl();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it worked!The firstY is multiplying the calculation by the square height (I'm using a 10px square, that's why it appears on my stage)

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Yea the squares I was using was close to 100px.. Well, cool, glad it's working